# Adding PartitionKey propery when inserting an entity in Azure table storage for nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

This is more of a call for help with an exception when calling `insertEntity()`.

I'm using Nodejs on Azure and editing in Monaco, and I've NPM-installed the latest version of azure storage.

The exception I encounter is: (full stack trace at the bottom)

> Unaught exception: Error: Parameter entityDescriptor.PartitionKey for function entityOperation should be an object     at ArgumentValidator._.extend.object

I'm basically taking my object to save, and creating 2 new properties: `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`. I give them string values. I'm [following the examples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/examples/). I'm not using entityGenerator, as the samples here don't, whereas the examples on the Azure Node developers portal do. I wouldn't mind using entityGenerator on the storage-specific properties if required, but the samples in the node azure github repo seem to suggest that you can use simple strings. The entityGenerator looks a bit ugly and cumbersome, honestly, as you'd have to code extra around the entity when you bring it back.

How can I adjust my code to solve this problem and call `insertEntity()` with success?

```
exports.saveTally = function(tally, callback) {
    var tableSvc = getAzureTableService();
     tableSvc.createTableIfNotExists("tally", function(error, result, response) {
if (!error) {    
  tally.PartitionKey="tally";
  tally.RowKey = tally.id;       
  tableSvc.insertEntity("tally", tally, function(error, result, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("*Error saving tally " + error.toString());
    }
    else {
      callback(tally.id);
    }
  });
}
});}
```

[image: stacktrace]

Answer (score 1):

The location of the Azure storage client library has changed to https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node. The samples you’re using are from the old location and from an older version of the library which is why they’re not working. You’ll find updated samples and code at the new location.

In the newer version, an Edm type must be specified for each table entity. This is because type is stored in the storage service and we want to make sure that we are storing what you intend. Each table entity is an object with the form {_:value, $:Edm.Type}.

Entity generator is a convenience feature which makes it simpler to construct table entity objects. We return entities in the form just mentioned and using this convenience feature will not change that in any way.

Comment: Just unbelievable! A such change without any backward compatibility, this is the Microsoft way ;-) All the documentation are still referring to the old one (http://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-table-storage/ ...) that makes me remember Silverlight ...

Comment: You can learn more about the new SDK here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/06/26/microsoft-azure-storage-client-module-for-node-js-v-0-2-0.aspx

Comment: @ThomasDecaux Unfortunately we have not yet updated the non-English Azure Storage Node documents. However, the equivalent English docs [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-table-storage/) are entirely up to date.

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft I understand, just make a link to the english version because I didnt find it on french google ;-( With a small note to indicate this is out of date, thanks for the link btw, I finish my work!

Comment: seems  like the nodejs sdk is making stuff unnecessary complicated.